# Unexpected Logging Behavior in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm facing an unusual behavior in my Angular application where I have an array that is logged before pushing an element to it, but the log displays the updated array with the pushed element. The array is then used in an HTML file with ngFor.

comoponent.ts file

```
interface OrderItem {
  quantity: number | null,
  product: any
}

export class Component{

orderItems: OrderItem[] = [{ quantity: null, product: {} }]

addProduct(): void {
    console.log(this.orderItems);
    this.orderItems.push({ quantity: null, product: {} })
  }

}
```

html file

```
<mat-form-field>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let ele of orderItems">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Product</mat-label>
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="ele.product">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let e of productlist" [value]="e._id" >{{e.productName}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Number of Items</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="number" [(ngModel)]="ele.quantity" placeholder="Enter the number of items">
        </mat-form-field>
        <br>
        </ng-container>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="addProduct()">
        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
      </button>

</mat-form-field>
```

The log output is very strange :

```
[{…}]
```

This gives the array with two objects : `[{ quantity: null, product: {} },{ quantity: null, product: {} }]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the explanation on the code.

```
interface OrderItem {
  quantity: number | null,
  product: any
}

export class Component{
// you have defined a property 'orderItems' which has a value set as  
// '[{ quantity: null, product: {} }]'
orderItems: OrderItem[] = [{ quantity: null, product: {} }]

addProduct(): void {
    // so the log will contain '[{ quantity: null, product: {} }]' when the
    // below line runs!
    console.log(this.orderItems);
    this.orderItems.push({ quantity: null, product: {} })
  }

}
```

So the expected output is the same as what was logged, to have a even better idea you can do [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), this will convert the object to a string with all the properties!

```
//  will print the formatted string of the 'orderItems'
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.orderItems, null, 4));
```

The console.log output can be interpreted as an array `[]` with a single object `{}` and the object has two properties `quantity` and `product`!

Here is a working example where only one object gets logged!

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-usrv6x?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: I guess you have misunderstood, I have edited the output again. It should have logged [{ quantity: null, product: {} }] but it logged this [{ quantity: null, product: {} },{ quantity: null, product: {} }]

Comment: @JashJasani updated my answer with a working example where only one object is logged

Comment: https://stackblitz-starters-egxp4a.stackblitz.io check this :)

Comment: @JashJasani `addProduct` called two times, first on `ngOnInit()` then on click of the button so we see two items! [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nm5nrl)

Comment: can you check this : https://imgur.com/a/6Bi6h9O

Comment: @JashJasani Which browser are you using, safari? maybe try updating the browser!

Comment: @JashJasani Its just showing the same reference on the browser, it happens I guess, because javascript stores arrays as locations in memory, so it will always have the latest value, to overcome this you can use the command `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.orderItems, null, 4)); `

Comment: Yes i guess that is the reason, it has the memory address of objects and arrays so if they change in future the browsers console is also updating the values.

Answer (score 0):

When you console log an object or an array, what you see in the console output is a "live" representation of that object, which is linked to the actual reference in the memory. Any updates to the object will be reflected in the view. When you use the `push` method, you are mutating an existing array.

When the `console.log` statement is ran, the `orderItems` array only has a single element in it, but it is mutated in the line immediately after it. This updates the value logged in the console to include the second item.

It is generally preferable to avoid mutations. Instead of pushing new items in the existing array, you can create a new array which has the new item added to the list of previous items. With this, console logging the value before and after the new assignment will show what you expect:

```js
console.log(this.orderItems); // [{ quantity: null, product: {} }]
this.orderItems = [...this.orderItems, { quantity: null, product: {} }];
console.log(this.orderItems); // [{ quantity: null, product: {} }, { quantity: null, product: {} }]
```

Comment: This seems to be the case with browser. I tried running this code in node it gives                                                                             let orderItems = [{quantity : 12, product : "Pen" }]

console.log("Before : ",orderItems);

orderItems.push({quantity : 456, product : "Car" })
console.log("After : ",orderItems);                                                                                                               Before :  [ { quantity: 12, product: 'Pen' } ]
After :  [ { quantity: 12, product: 'Pen' }, { quantity: 456, product: 'Car' } ]

Comment: But on browser it logs ````[{ quantity: null, product: {} },{ quantity: null, product: {} }]````

Comment: In Node, the console output is like a static string - it cannot change, while the browser output is dynamic. Behind the scenes, the same thing is happening, but you cannot see it due to the different ways the output works.

Comment: I also tried this https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-egxp4a?file=src%2Fmain.ts it works differently on stackblitz.

Comment: The [Stackblitz console](https://developer.stackblitz.com/guides/user-guide/ide-whats-on-your-screen#console) is a lightweight replacement of the browser DevTools console. It seems like it cannot display objects the way the browser's native console can.